# R: `lubridate` cannot recognise timezone "SG" in Windows

Tags: r, timezone, lubridate

I've been using R in Debian for 5 years and have always set `tz()` as "SG" - for 'Singapore'. When I port my code to Windows 8.1 (installed with the latest `R` 3.6.0 and `lubridate` 1.7.4), I hit into the following error:

```
> library(lubridate)
> a <- Sys.time()
> tz(a) <- "SG" 
Error in C_force_tz(time, tz = tzone, roll) :    
    CCTZ: Unrecognized output timezone: "SG"
```

**MY INVESTIGATION**

Using my Debian VM, I updated `lubridate` from v1.6.0 (which has been working fine all along) to the latest v1.7.4, and true enough, it showed the same error.

Thinking that I've found the bug, I went back to Windows and installed lubridate 1.6.0, but lo-and-behold! It hit a similar error:

```
> library(lubridate)
> a <- Sys.time()
> tz(a)<-"SG"
Warning messages:
1: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(lt) : unknown timezone 'SG'
2: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(ct) : unknown timezone 'SG'
```

**My Questions**

**Naturally, my questions are: 
(i) Why is the above error happening in Debian when I upgraded `lubridate` to v1.7.4? and 
(ii) How can I resolve the error in Windows using either lubridate v1.6.0 or v1.7.4?**

Last I checked, Singapore is still a country and according to [Microsoft Default Timezones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones), Singapore's timezone is 'SG' (middle of the page).

After all these years, I've never completely understood date/time and timezones. Hope someone wiser than me can help enlighten.

**SYSTEM INFO**

```
# Windows 8.1 (where the error occurred)
R: 3.6.0 (64-bit)
lubridate: both 1.6.0 and 1.7.4 give error

# Debian Jessie
R: 3.3.3 (64-bit)
lubridate: 1.6.0 (NO error) and 1.7.4 (has error)
```

Comment: Take a look at the results from the `OlsonNames()` function. that should give you a list of known timezones. It doesn't look like the country codes can be used as a time zone, but you can do `tz(a) <- "Singapore"`

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, I was just about to post an update saying that I found out about this `OlsonNames()`. Have just tried 'Singapore' instead of 'SG' and it works! Yes! Now my new question: have I been doing it wrong all along when I used 'SG'?

Comment: @MrFlick, would you like to convert your comment to a proposed solution so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of "official" timezone names from the `OlsonNames()` function. It doesn't look like country codes like "SG" are on that list, but "Singapore" is. So you can do

```
tz(a) <- "Singapore"
```